# JavaScript inside KO Template

Tags: javascript, html, templates, knockout.js, knockout-templating

How to put script inside knockout template?

This doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/html" id="some-template">
    <div>
    ...
        <script type="text/javascript"> <!-- This is the problem -->
            CoinWidgetCom.go({
                wallet_address: "ENTER-YOUR-BITCOIN-WALLET-ADDRESS"
                , currency: "bitcoin"
                , counter: "count"
                , alignment: "bl"
                , qrcode: true
                , auto_show: false
                , lbl_button: "Donate"
                , lbl_address: "My Bitcoin Address:"
                , lbl_count: "donations"
                , lbl_amount: "BTC"
            });
        </script>
    ...
    </div>
</script>

...

<script src="http://coinwidget.com/widget/coin.js"></script>
```

[This](http://coinwidget.com/) is the script that I'm trying to run inside each of the elements that use `some-template`. Script could maybe be modified, but I would rather use original version.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? Why couldn't you put the JavaScript outside the HTML template?

Comment: @p.s.w.g I have some external script that creates DOM elements inside element where script is called.

Comment: What is the script? And why do you have to nest it within another `<script>`

Comment: @AleksandarToplek I would suspect (though I'm not sure) that this kind of thing is specifically disallowed to guard against [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) scenarios.

Comment: @p.s.w.g With "external" I meant third-party... sorry about misscommunication.

Comment: @p.s.w.g As for cross site scripting problem, if server that serves content allows it in headers then it's ok...

Comment: You do not need to dynamically load that javascript and therefore do not need to put that within your template. Just load it with the rest of the page and use it...

Comment: @JeffMercado There are two scripts, one is to load the jquery plugin, and this one calls .go function which creates elements inside element it was called from. The second one is the problem.

Comment: Look at the source... you just need to call the function. The script itself does not (should not) need to be loaded dynamically.  And it certainly does not need to be in a template.  That's not what templates are meant for.

Comment: @JeffMercado Its the method that needs to be called from element it initializes, thats the problem. I edited sample code, take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is not possible. I don't think `script` tags with executable javascript inside a `text/html` script will have their code executed when the template is rendered.

However, like other commenters said: you don't need to do this. Rework your design, make use of Knockout's features for these type of things. There are several alternative solutions, including:

Creating your own bindingHandler to activate the widget on a rendered template. You have posted only a small portion of code, but here's what that would look like:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.myWidget = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
        console.log('Initializing widget with ' + ko.toJSON(allBindings()['myWidget']));
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever any observables/computeds that are accessed change
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
    }
};

var VmForTemplate = function() { }

var ViewModel = function() {
  this.subVm = new VmForTemplate();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="some-template">
  <div data-bind='myWidget: {
                      wallet_address: "ENTER-YOUR-BITCOIN-WALLET-ADDRESS"
                      , currency: "bitcoin"
                      , counter: "count"
                      , alignment: "bl"
                      , qrcode: true
                      , auto_show: false
                      , lbl_button: "Donate"
                      , lbl_address: "My Bitcoin Address:"
                      , lbl_count: "donations"
                      , lbl_amount: "BTC"
                    }'>
  ... template ...
  </div>
</script>


<!-- ko template: { name: 'some-template', data: subVm } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Alternatively, use the `afterRender` attribute of [the `template` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), like so:

```js
var VmForTemplate = function() { }

var ViewModel = function() {
  this.subVm = new VmForTemplate();
  this.initWidget = function() { CoinWidgetCom.go({
                wallet_address: "ENTER-YOUR-BITCOIN-WALLET-ADDRESS"
                , currency: "bitcoin"
                , counter: "count"
                , alignment: "bl"
                , qrcode: true
                , auto_show: false
                , lbl_button: "Donate"
                , lbl_address: "My Bitcoin Address:"
                , lbl_count: "donations"
                , lbl_amount: "BTC"
            }); };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="some-template">
    <div>
       Template. No javascript here.
    </div>
</script>

<script>
  // Mock the widget
  var CoinWidgetCom = { go: function(opts) { console.log('Running widget with options: ' + ko.toJSON(opts)); } };
</script>

<!-- ko template: { name: 'some-template', data: subVm, afterRender: initWidget } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Will try the first solution, looks great.